# Prove the following identity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, alternative-proof

I am having some trouble proving following identity without use of induction, with which it is trivial.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2(m+1)(m+2)}$$

I did expand the expression:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\left( \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2(n+2)} \right)$$

I have no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: The identity you're trying to prove should have $m$'s in it.

Comment: Oops. Sorry!! My bad.

Comment: The summation is from $n = 1$ to $n = m$, so the right-hand side surely has $m$'s, not $n$'s.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Thank You.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\frac1{2n}-\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{2(n+2)}\right)&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)-\left(\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)-\sum_{n=2}^{m+1}\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)\right)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 10):

A straightforward way. Write the sum as

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\left(\frac{1}{2n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)(n+2)}\right)=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2(m+1)(m+2)}$$
Q.E.D. (the sum telescopes)

Comment: @user1709828: welcome!

Comment: I was just going to post that
$$
\frac1{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{n(n+1)}-\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)
$$
Too late...

Comment: @robjohn: hehe. :-)

Comment: It forced me to write a more general answer :-)

Answer (score 6):

This is a special case $(k=3)$ of the following
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=k}^m\frac1{\binom{n}{k}}
&=\frac{k}{k-1}\sum_{n=k}^m\left(\frac1{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}-\frac1{\binom{n\vphantom{1}}{k-1}}\right)\\
&=\frac{k}{k-1}\left(1-\frac1{\binom{m}{k-1}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Noting that $n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k-1)=k!\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1{k!\binom{n+k-1}{k}}=\frac1{k-1}\left(\frac1{(k-1)!}-\frac1{(k-1)!\binom{(m+1)+(k-2)}{k-1}}\right)
$$
that is,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^m\underbrace{\frac1{n(n+1)\dots(n+k-1)}}_{k\text{ factors}}=\frac1{k-1}\left(\frac1{(k-1)!}-\underbrace{\frac1{(m+1)(m+2)\dots(m+k-1)}}_{k-1\text{ factors}}\right)
$$
Substituting $k=3$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac12\left(\frac12-\frac1{(m+1)(m+2)}\right)
$$

Comment: This almost qualifies as a [swatting flies with a sledgehammer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172509) answer.

Comment: @RickDecker: It's simply a generalization of Chris's Sister's answer. As such, it does pack a bit more power, but it is not that complicated.

Comment: @robjohn: nice. A generalization is welcome! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: by partial fraction

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{n+1}+\frac{C}{n+2}\Longrightarrow$$

$$1=A(n+1)(n+2)+Bn(n+2)+Cn(n+1)$$

Choosing smartly values for $\,n\,$ above , we get

$$1=2A\Longrightarrow A=\frac{1}{2}\;\;,\;\;1=-B\Longrightarrow B=-1\;\;,\;\;1=2C\Longrightarrow C=\frac{1}{2}$$

so

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}\right)$$

So summing up

$$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\right]$$

Now just check that there's a lot of cancellation up there...

Comment: I don't get it: what is "totally redundant"?

Comment: The partial fraction computation was not necessary. It's already done in question so not needed and Brian M. Scott already had the remaining portion. Never mind!. It is self contained and good. Thank You.

Comment: You realize that nobody here can't look what other people do while writing an answer, so it may happen with very basic questions that there are two or more answers that appeared within a few minutes from each other and very similar...you're not a newbie in this site, you should know this.