# How do we calculate this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+p)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that this sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+p)}$$ ($p$ fixed) converges which can be easily proved using the ratio criterion, but I couldn't calculate it.

I need help in this part.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: for $p=0$ the series won't converge, for every other case i would try to part the fractions

Comment: For $p=1$ the series telescopes: $\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$. Try to see if this idea extends?

Comment: yeah it works, $$\frac{1}{p^2\cdot (n-1)!}$$

Comment: This is of the  form $x^{(p)}$  which has a well known sum.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee What do you mean? which series is of this form?

Comment: By  $x^{(p)}$ I mean the rising factorial. It's sum(indefinite) is $\frac{x^{(p+1)}}{p+1}$ The proof is similar to the one done below.

Comment: Try to do something similar to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/282317/39722).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** 
$$\frac{p}{n(n+1)\cdots(n+p)}=\frac{1}{(n)(n+1)\cdots (n+p-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+p)}.$$

Comment: ah, beat me to it.